# Synchronizing blockchain data to external hard disk

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I've been struggling to find an answer for this, but it seems like there is no solid, well-documented answer for this.

`How can I use mounted external drive for blockchain synchronization?`

I installed bitcoin core in my ubuntu 16.04 by using ppa package,

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoind -y
```

and I mounted 200GB hard disk to synchronize all blockchain data.

`/mnt/xvdb/`

I know the data directory will be made `~/.bitcoin`

once i start synchronizing by typing `bitcoind &` in linux.

How could I possibly make it synchronizing to the mounted hard disk ?